# $http and Streams?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to read the [App.net public stream](http://developers.app.net/docs/resources/post/streams/#retrieve-the-global-stream). However when I use a simple `$http.get()` I only get one response.

```
$http
  .get('https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts/stream/global')
  .success(function (results) {
    console.log('received results', results);
  })
;
```

How do I connect to http streams in AngularJS?
Is there even a way or would I have to use something like WebSockets?

Comment: *rtm*, the structure is: `{data: [...]}`, in your case: `results.data` will contain 20 entries.

Comment: @Yoshi that ist correct and I can see that easily in the console. However, I'd have to make another `$http.get();` in order to fetch new posts - but I want to access the http stream and rather have long polling instead.

Comment: I think that's more of a question regarding the api you're using. In the docs, I don't see where it says that any long polling would be possible. Simply *Return the 20 most recent Posts from the Global stream.*.

Comment: @Yoshi oic. Seems like the docs use the term 'stream' ambiguously. I assume I was looking in the wrong spot. Will update my question if appropriate - or answer it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http` is a single request only. For long polling, call it periodically with `$interval`.

```js
function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
  function poll() {
    $http.get('...').success(function(data) {
      $scope.posts = data;
    });
    $timeout(poll, 10000);
  }

  poll();
}
```

You could also create a service to encapsulate this logic, but you would need a fixed data structure to be updated, instead of changing the result. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14945305/179138).

Comment: If this is a persistent connection though, you'd rather go with Socket.io and a custom service. [Here's a example](https://github.com/mhevery/angular-node-socketio).

Comment: I believe its $timeout instead of $interval ?

Comment: You're right. I've created a `$interval` service and forgot it's custom. :)