# angular dot notation better explanation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax, polling, ajax-polling

I was looking for a solution about [polling data using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944936/angularjs-global-http-polling-service) and I found here at stackoverflow.

In this solution (shown bellow) it is used a javascript object to return the response (`data.response`) and if I try to replace that `data` object for a *simple javascript array* it **doesn't work**, I would like to know exactly why I need to go with **dot notation** and why a single array doesn't work? (It would be great links or explanation with examples)

```
app.factory('Poller', function($http, $timeout) {
  var data = { response: {}, calls: 0 };
  var poller = function() {
    $http.get('data.json').then(function(r) {
      data.response = r.data;
      data.calls++;
      $timeout(poller, 1000);
    });      
  };
  poller();

  return {
    data: data
  };
});
```

Trying to summarize my goal (what I want to really understand): where is `var data = { response: {}, calls: 0 };` could be `var data = {};` and then the `response.data` would be setted directly to data `data = r.data` and  `return {data: data};`, why do I need to rely on dot notation?

Comment: I remove the dot, it still works http://plnkr.co/edit/lIltfOWL4YObm5oRB13W?p=preview

Comment: But you still access response trough `data.response` I meant: instead of `var data = { response: {}, calls: 0 };` be `var data = [];`

Comment: I tried to replace on your example and it is failing now http://plnkr.co/edit/kCV95VJlCpSq6etVNJVf?p=preview

Comment: Because every time when poller is called, data is pointing to a new object `data = r.data;`

Comment: ohh I think I get it. Since I'm using the same object instance (`data.prop = value`) the only thing will change each time is the value and if I try to use `[]`, `{}` or a simple value it makes me lose the reference in the view. (**binding**: view is pointing to an object that doesn't exist anymore). Did I get it right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say if we change the factory in this way:

```
app.factory('Poller', function($http, $timeout) {
  var d = {};
  var poller = function() {
    $http.get('data.json').then(function(r) {
      d = r.data;
      $timeout(poller, 1000);
    });
  };
  poller();

  return d;
});
```

In the controller, the statement `$scope.data = Poller;` assign d object to $scope.data, so the object relationship is like this after the initialization

```
$scope.data -> d -> r.data
```

When poller() is called again in 1 sec, d is replaced with an new object, so the object relationship will be

```
$scope.data -> d* -> r.data (d* is a new object)
```

so the angularjs's data binding will be broken since there is no way to trace to the r.data since d* is a brand new object with different prototype.

With dot notation, after the initialization the object relationship never changes since the periodic calls to poll() doesn't create new object `d` but it just keeping updating the response field with new `r.data` object.

```
$scope.data -> d.response -> r.data
```

Comment: **Thank you very much** I can't vote you up (and for some reason I don't know how to raise your reputation) but I already mark your answer as correct.