# select2 values not changing on angular model changed

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, angular-ui-select

i am unable to change selected values inside select2 in my controller.

```
<select id="drptabselect" ng-model="selectedTab" class="form-control select2"
ng-options="x.Title for x in tabnames">
</select>
```

i have ajax call where data.Tab returning as follow

```
$scope.selectedTab = data.Tab;
```

ajax tab result as below

```
"Tab": {
"$id": "2",
"ID": 4,
"Title": "FirstTab"
},
```

if i try to print the

```
<span>{{selectedTab}}</span>
```

it gives expected value after assignmnet
as

```
{"$id": "2","ID": "4","Title": "FirstTab"}
```

Unfortunatly the same not applied to select2 dropdown.
there it still shows last selected value.
How can populate the value in dropdown box too?

my $scope.tabnames looks like this

```
[{"$id": "1",
"ID": 4,
"Title": "FirstTab"
},
{"$id": "2",
"ID": 5,
"Title": "Secondtab"
},
{"$id": "3",
"ID": 6,
"Title": "Thirdtab"
}]
```

i am using regular select2 library (not angualr-ui)

Comment: Can you replicate the issue on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/)

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/pJQBfQQ5cA9msc6fXErp

here select2 is not working
but same issue is there for select
hope if this can be fixed, it will give answer to my solution..
basically populating select value inside controller

Comment: Hi there, check my answer if that helps you out.

Comment: My select2 was inside controller, icant see any solution in ur code

Answer (score 1):

One of Angular JS gotchas when working with ngModel is to use [dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128323/if-you-are-not-using-a-dot-in-your-angularjs-models-you-are-doing-it-wrong) by going further one level (see also [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039917/angular-dot-notation-better-explanation)). Try :

```
$scope.controllerData.selectedTab = data.Tab;
$scope.controllerData.tabnames = ...
```

controllerData is just an arbitrary name, you may choose whatever fits your need.

Also, is there a particular reason for tabnames to be an array with a single entry and containing objects?

Comment: HI Christian Bonato, Thanks for your hint,
 Can you please elaborate on controllerData?
My identifier selectedTab  is declare dat root level as
      $scope.selectedTab =[]

about why tabnames is array,
This is how ajax responce,
in that rest of text input controlls data update works perfectly fine with statements like 
$scope.Title = data.Title;

only problem is for select2 dropdown,
      {
     "Title": "Usersname",
     "ControlName": "txtUsersname",
     "Tab": {
     "$id": "3",
     "ID": 4,
     "Title": "FirstTab"
     },
}

Comment: here select2 is not working but same issue is there for select hope if this can be fixed, it will give answer to my solution.. basically populating select value inside controller –

Comment: plunker is here : plnkr.co/edit/pJQBfQQ5cA9msc6fXErp

Answer (score 0):

You were having the `select2` tab outside the controller defination, i think that is the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
   <link data-require="select2@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" />

    <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="select2.full.js"></script>


  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div>
{{message}}
                  <br />
      <select id="drptabselect" ng-model="selectedTab" class="form-control select2" ng-options="x.Title for x in tabnames"></select>
    </div>
      <input type="button" ng-click="setselect()" value="set select2">
  </body>



 {{selectedTab}}

</html>
```