# why factory is preffered to service when using $http.get

Tags: angularjs, service, factory

I'm using anularJS in a project, I need a service in order  to get JSONs with $http.get method, I think that a service would have an easier to read syntax:

```
app.service('ApiService' , function($http)
{
  var self = this;
  self.user = {};
  self.user.getByName = function(){};
  self.user.getByRate = function(){};

  self.events = {};

  self.events.getList = function(){};
  self.events.getByDate = function(){};

  return ({
    user : self.user,
    events : self.events
  });

});
```

and then you can call it like:

```
$scope.reople = ApiService.use.getList('some url');
```

but from too many pages (like [this](http://blog.pluralsight.com/angularjs-step-by-step-services) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505760/angularjs-processing-http-response-in-service) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937318/convert-angular-http-get-function-to-a-service)) I've seen, seem it's more popular to use factory as a better approach. can you please explain me:

1. why is factory preferred  and more popular than service?
2. which is more extendable and maintainable for a group work or for a developer working on an existing code?

Comment: see here for a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angular-js-service-vs-provider-vs-factory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.service()` is just a derived version of `.factory()` and both are derived from `.provider()`, all of them are for registering services to use via DI across the app.

Please see [AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048) if you would like to dive into detail.

The reason of why `.factory()` is popular probably because:

- the `.service()` is too specific, you can only pass in a constructor function
- the `.provider()` is too verbose, not all the time a service should be configurable

The `.factory()` is something in the middle that serve the needs of almost common usages.

```
app.factory('ApiService' , function($http) {
  function ApiService() {
    var self = this;
    self.user = {};
    self.user.getByName = function(){};
    self.user.getByRate = function(){};

    self.events = {};
    self.events.getList = function(){};
    self.events.getByDate = function(){};
  };

  return new ApiService();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

factory is not preferred to service. based on the type of response you need it defers, do you need a callback or to return the value of results? respectively the suitable is service or factory.